# Selenium web scraping site with pagination

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've been playing around learning how to create web scrapers using Selenium. One thing I'm struggling with is scraping pages with pagination. I've written a script that i thought would scrape every page

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import getpass
import datetime
import pandas as pd
custom_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
custom_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=custom_options)
driver.get("https://lr.caa.cz/letecky-rejstrik?lang=en")
data =[]

while(True):
    try:
        table_body = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "tbody")))
        table_body_rows = table_body.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/div/main/div/div/app-avreg-list/nav/div/app-pagination/div/a[3]/i')))
        for i in table_body_rows:
            row_data = []
            table_data = i.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
            for j in table_data:
                row_data.append(j.text.strip())
            data.append(row_data)
        button.click()
    except:
        
        break

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
driver.quit()
```

It scrapes the first page but then it doesn't seem to go beyond that. This the result i get:

```
                  0          1        2     3
0            Glider  MDM-1 FOX  OK-1213      
1            Glider  MDM-1 FOX  OK-7801      
2            Glider       A 15  OK-7906      
3    Powered glider    SZD-45A  OK-6902      
4    Powered glider    SZD-45A  OK-8903      
5   Hot-air balloon         AB  OK-9004      
6   Hot-air balloon         AB  OK-4012      
7   Hot-air balloon         AB  OK-4014      
8   Hot-air balloon         AB  OK-7006      
9   Hot-air balloon         AB  OK-7004      
10                        None     None  None
```

I've looked at the xpath of the pagination button on the site and it seems correct in the script.

Any thoughts on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `presence_of_element_located()` use `element_to_be_clickable()` and following css selector or xpath to identify the element.

```
 button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'app-pagination a:nth-of-type(3)')))
```

OR

```
  button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//app-pagination//a)[3]")))
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried replacing the line with `element_to_be_clickable` with the line `button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/app-root/div/main/div/div/app-avreg-list/nav/div/app-pagination/div/a[3]/i")))` but its still returning just the first page. Even when i also try `button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//app-pagination//a)[3]")))`